# Using XSD.exe to generate non-nillable field with minOccurs = 1 for reference type

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have the following class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(TypeName = "CoreAccount")]
public abstract class Account
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Microsoft's XSD.exe to generate a XML schema from the class. The 'AccountNumber' property is being generated in the XSD as follows:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountNumber" type="xs:string" />
```

I am happy that this element is required but I do **not** want to accept an empty (nillable) value.

I know that the easy option is to manually update the XSD to include:

```
nillable="false"
```

But I want to be able to do this programmatically so the XSD.exe tool will generate this. Does anybody have any suggestions? I have read elsewhere that this is a limitation of .NET but am wondering if anybody else has any ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you set `IsNullable` to false?

Comment: Setting IsNullable to false results in minOccurs changing to 0.

Comment: Your class doesn't match up with the xsd output, you should change the attribute on your class to be `[XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given class

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(TypeName = "CoreAccount")]
public abstract class Account
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
}
```

Will always produce an xsd with the following element

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountNumber" type="xs:string" />
```

This is because the default value for the `nillable` attribute is `false` See - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_element.asp

> nillable
>   Optional. Specifies whether an explicit null value can be assigned to the element. True enables an instance of the element to have the null attribute set to true. The null attribute is defined as part of the XML Schema namespace for instances. Default is false

From looking at the documentation of `XSD.exe` there isn't a way of explicitly generating the xsd (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)